# What is wrong with my question ? What can I do to improve it?

Tags: discussion

This is the Question I am talking about :
[In Cricket T20 World Cup 2021, why are Bangladesh & SriLanka Demoted to Group A/B with Afghanistan Promoted to Group 2?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/26453/in-cricket-t20-world-cup-2021-why-are-bangladesh-srilanka-demoted-to-group-a)

What is wrong with my question ?
What can I do to improve it ?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't vote on the question, and don't really know much about it, but a few details that might suggest why it was downvoted.

First, it's not really clear what you're asking.  This may be a language issue, which is totally understandable, but as an English speaker I can't really tell: are you asking "upon what were the rankings based whereby Afghanistan was higher ranked than Bangladesh and Sri Lanka"?  That would be on topic, but you would want to clearly ask that.  (The answer would, presumably, be something like "Matches at XYZ tournaments over the time AA-BB-CC to DD-EE-FF" are considered, with X points for a win".)

Or are you asking a more broad question - something like "How did they manage to screw up so badly as to be ranked below them"?  That kind of question is not on topic here - it's opinion based, not something you can answer just with "facts" per se.

The lack of clarity as to what your question was asking, most likely, led to the downvote.  (Also note, it's just one downvote to zero upvotes - and we don't have a ton of users, so you're just looking at basically one person's opinion.  It's pretty common to not get many upvotes, especially if you're talking about a sport other than (association) football, or an American sport, where the plurality of our "regular" users are from.)

Comment: Thanks for Perspectives & Suggestions. It does indeed look like "Opinion", but on the border-line ; at least, it is not worse than https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/26433/is-being-a-bigger-country-in-terms-of-population-one-of-the-main-reasons-india-i & https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/25557/isnt-the-cricket-toss-just-an-illusion-of-control & https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/24579/former-british-colonies-and-cricket ; No matter, I will try to Improve my question & answer.

Comment: @Prem Particularly the "Why is India good", I'd agree that's also opinion, and while I make a rule of not closing questions on sports I don't have a strong background in about that the other mods know more of and have interacted with, I would otherwise close it.  The second question, though, is asking a very precise question in a sense - not in every sense, but in a sense; it's asking if the toss has a purpose beyond the randomization.  That could have a direct, factual answer.  The third is also answerable to some extent - it's more of a *history* question, really.

Comment: I hope you realize that I am not arguing with you, I am just Discussing .... While the third Q is about "History", my Q could be considered "Recent History" or even "Current Affairs" which could be answerable (though I did attempt to answer my own Q) .... The Examples I listed were selected with tag Cricket, otherwise there are worse Examples .... [[ On a light-hearted note, sometimes, it seems like one DownVoter is following me around, like a negative Guardian Angel !! ]]